# How to pass some constants in Boosts's brent_find_minima()?

Tags: c++, boost, arguments

**How can I pass some constants in boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima() from main()?**

```
struct func
{
  template <class T>
  T operator()(T const& x)
  { //
      T Wnew = 20.0/9.0*720.0; // Goal is to pass it through main()
      T W = 2500;  // Goal is to pass it through main()
      return abs(Wnew/2/x - atan(W/2/x));
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // How can I pass Wnew and W values while calling boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima() from main()
    std::pair<double, double> r = boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima(func(), 1.0, 2000.0, std::numeric_limits<double>::digits);
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    std::cout << "x at minimum = " << r.first << ", f(" << r.first << ") = " << r.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: formerlyknownas_463035818 has answered your question. I would point out you can [wrap and/or just use a lambda](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/661bd5db3bf31a3b)

Comment: @lakeweb actually i planned to mention it in the answer but then forgot, now I will just steal the idea from you :P

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, be my guest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you want is to create different instances of `func` with different values for `W` and `Wnew`. You are almost there, just give your `func` some state:

```
struct func
{
  double Wnew;
  double W;
  func(double Wnew, double W) : Wnew(Wnew),W(W) {}

  double operator()(double const& x)
  { 
      return abs(Wnew/2/x - atan(W/2/x));
  }
};
```

And then create an instance like this:

```
double Wnew = 1.0;
double W = 2.0;
auto r = boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima(func(Wnew,W), 1.0, 2000.0, std::numeric_limits<double>::digits);
                                                  // ^^
```

I was a bit puzzled by your `operator()` being a template and changed that. If you had good reasons for it, simply make it a template again.

PS: Since C++11, there are [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that allow a much terser syntax for functors.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually weak in passing value through constructors. But your solution helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I like the lambda approach the best:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/tools/minima.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double W = 2500;
    double Wnew = 20.0/9.0*720.0;
    if (argc == 3) {
        double W = std::stod(argv[1]);
        double Wnew = std::stod(argv[2]);
    }

    auto f = [&W, &Wnew](double x)->double {
        return std::abs(Wnew/2/x - atan(W/2/x));
    };

    std::pair<double, double> r = boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima(f, 1.0, 2000.0, std::numeric_limits<double>::digits);
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    std::cout << "x at minimum = " << r.first << ", f(" << r.first << ") = " << r.second << std::endl;
}
```

The documentation for `brent_find_minima` was written pre-C++11, and uses what now should be regarded as overly verbose syntax. The post C++11 boost.math documentation examples (like the quadrature routines) all use lambdas.